# Como usar o this!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que cada botão quando clicado fique amarelo e os outros voltem ao normal...segue o código e o fiddle:

```
$( "#botoes" ).each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(".botaoativo").removeClass('botaoativo');
        $(this).addClass('botaoativo');
    });
 });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koq945bt/5/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu caso, faltou iterar sobre os botões, você iterou apenas na `div#botoes`, precisa iterar sobre os filhos dessa div que engloba os botões.

Dessa forma seu código ficaria:

```
$("#botoes div").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(".botaoativo").removeClass('botaoativo');
        $(this).addClass('botaoativo');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utqz1fa0/) dessa solução.

Outra forma seria iterar sobre os filhos, independente de quais sejam, através da função [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$("#botoes").children().each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(".botaoativo").removeClass('botaoativo');
        $(this).addClass('botaoativo');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vo8y6h57/) dessa solução.

Comment: Tem um Fiddle desse pra eu dar uma brincada?

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer mas fechei, vou refazer e coloco aqui.

Comment: Pronto @CiganoMorrisonMendez, inclui os dois.

Comment: Ficou bacana. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Baseado no seu Fiddle, [fiz outro](http://jsfiddle.net/koq945bt/6/).

O `.click` é um evento que deve monitorar os botões por `class` pra ser eficiente. Ou seja, defini a `class` para todos os seus botões e retirei a `div` de fora, que não tinha utilidade no exemplo.

O código ficou assim:

```
$(".botoes").click(function() {
    $(".botoes").removeClass('botaoativo');
    $(this).addClass('botaoativo');
});
```

Ou seja, para cada classe `.botoes`, monitora-se o comportameno `.click`. Ao clicar, remove de todos os botões a classe `botaoativo` (que deixa o botão amarelo), e adiciona-se `botaoativo` apenas no botão clicado (onde uso o `this`).

Comment: O `.click` vai monitorar igualmente todos os seletores aplicados, independentemente se for classe, ID, tag, pseudo classe, find, children, parent ou qualquer outra função de seleção, ele não fara distinção nenhuma desde que receba o(s) elemento(s)...

Comment: Sim. Portanto, `.botoes`. Está mais claro no Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Nessas situações que muitos esquecem que pode-se agrupar vários seletores tanto no CSS quanto no Jquery:

**Jquery:**

```
$('#botao1, #botao2, #botao3, #botao4').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('botaoativo')) return false; // presumindo que tenha mais comandos que não devem ser re-executados em caso de click no botão ativo
    $(".botaoativo").removeClass('botaoativo');
    $(this).addClass('botaoativo');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#botao1, #botao2, #botao3, #botao4 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#botao1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/bfxwr75w/)